# I want to remove id from URL in my laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my Laravel application, I have created url: like "www.example.com/rent/property-for-rent/45"
but here, I want to remove id from the last and concatenate id with my 2nd parameter that is, "property for rent" like : "www.example.com/rent/property-for-rent-45".

In the Controller function get 3 parameters

```
public function single_properties(Request $request, $property_purpose, $slug, $id)
```

In the Blade file

```
{{url(strtolower($property->property_purpose).'/'.$property->property_slug)}}
```

In the Web.php File

```
Route::get('{property_purpose}/{slug}/{id}', 'PropertiesController@single_properties');
```

I have tried to  reduce parameter from the function, blade and route, but didn't work for me.
can anyone please help me out, I am poorly trapped in it,

Comment: what is the error? what if the slug contains an int in it?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it like this:

```
public function singleProperties(Request $request, $property_purpose, $slug, $id)
{
    // old url: example.com/rent/property-for-rent/45
    // new url: example.com/rent/property-for-rent-45
    $newUrl = $property_purpose . '/' . $slug . '-' . $id;

    return view('your.view.blade', [
        'new_url' => $newUrl,
    ]);
}
```

And in your blade call `{{ $new_url }}`

Comment: This solution is not working. Upper function "SingleProperties" used to get records and display as a single property. actually we fetch records on id basis. So, what I should do Now?

Comment: So you want to do this for every record you fetch? Can you show me the contents of a property, what data it contains?

Answer (score 0):

You can do in a simple way. As the URL is like this:-

```
www.example.com/rent/property-for-rent-45
```

Url structure for route will be like:   /rent/slug-id
Means id is concatenated with slug. so laravel will consider it as full string as slug only. We will define this and later in controller will extract id from the slug.

So in routes/ web.php you can define like:-

In the Web.php File
Route::get('{property_purpose}/{slug}','PropertiesController@single_properties');

In the Blade file

```
{{url(strtolower($property->property_purpose).'/'.$property->property_slug-$property->property_id)}}
```

In Controller File You an define like:-

Here Slug variable you have to parse using known PHP function. As with the information, you know id is coming in last after - symbol. So you can explode slug variable and take the id coming last after -

```
public function singleProperties(Request $request, $property_purpose, $slug)
{

$slugarr=explode('-',$slug);
$id=$slugarr[count($slugarr)+1];// As index starts from 0, for getting last you have to this

//Now you got the $id you can fetch record you want this id

}
```